# Can you change SharePoint Name but not the URL?

Tags: rename

I want to change the name of the site on my homepage but not change the URL.  Is that possible

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the homepage's title?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your site > click the cog icon on the top right of the page > click Site Settings > under the Look and Feel heading click Title, Description and Logo > change your site's Title here and, optionally, also its URL.

This will change your site's heading/name without changing the URL.